# Как в java реализовать прослушку мыши и клавы без привязки к объекту?

Tags: listener, java, key

Изучаю java недавно. Пытаюсь написать синхронизатор мыши и клавиатуры на 2-х компах для своих нужд. Пока речь о jframe проблем нет, но мне нужно реализовать listner так, чтобы он слушал мышь и клавиатуру независимо от того, какое окно активно.

С перемещением мыши решил проблему с помощью `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();`.

А вот с кликами и клавиатурой сложнее - listenerы с ними работают, насколько я понимаю, только в определенных объектах.

Посоветуйте, как сделать, чтобы listener или работал без привязки к объекту, или фокусировался на тот объект, который в фокусе во время выполнения (лучше первое). Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение 1**

По [ссылке](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx) Keyboard hooks, через WinApi.

**Решение 2**

Есть также [библиотека](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) для получения "глобального" доступа к клавиатуре и мыши.

Comment: Годно, а можно пример использования?

Comment: Примеры по использованию либы у них тут есть: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples

Относительно первого решения там же проект прицеплен с примером по ссылке скачайте, там вроде надо только зарегистрироваться для этого.